# pip not working with non-root user on RHEL 6 server

Tags: linux, python, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6, pip

I have a server running RHEL 6 with Python 2.6.6. I am having trouble using pip with Python as a non-root user.

I am able to install pip packages and use them as root. However, when I try to run pip as a non-root user, I get this error:

```
[~]$ pip install requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip
```

Likewise, while I can use `requests` for example after installing as root, I cannot then use it as a non-root user.

```
[~]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 22 2015, 08:34:51)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-15)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
>>>
```

I am running pip 8.1.1:

```
[~]# pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```

Comment: I checked to see that the site-packages folder has read permission by the user and it does.

Comment: You must have some custom version of pip.  On RHEL 6 you should be using python-pip from EPEL, which is currently at version 7.1.0-1.  It also sounds like your user and root are not seeing the same site-packages, which could indicate a custom compiled version of Python.  What is the output of `rpm -qf $(which python)` as both your user and root?